# How to use iTextSharp to read PDF files that contains Chinese characters

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

When I use iTextSharp plugin to read text from a PDF file on .Net Framework which contains Chinese characters,
then what I've read are messy code, I've tried to use 
`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`, `Unicode,BigEndianUnicode`, and `GB2312`, `GBK`, `GB18030` to get the right characters , but it doesn't work.
I've searching on the internet and find that some one say read Chinese character need any other plugin,but he didn't say which plugin,so I need help,Thanks very much!

Comment: *When I use iTextSharp plugin to read text from a PDF file* - how did you use it? There are good ways and bad ways, and unfortunately there are many samples out there proposing the bad ways. Thus, give some sample code, preferably a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](sscce.org). Furthermore, have you checked whether your PDF contains sufficient information for text extraction? Thus, also provide a sample PDF.

Comment: Could you provide sample PDf? I will check and let you back.